# Trying to set SRID for a Geometry

Tags: postgresql, srid

I imported precinct data from the [Harvard Dataverse](https://dataverse.harvard.edu/dataset.xhtml?persistentId=doi:10.7910/DVN/NH5S2I) into Postgres 9.3 using the PostGIS Shapefile Import/Export Manager.

It creates a geom column with a SRID of 0.  I think the data is projected as SRID 4326 as I was able to view a map of it using TileMill when I chose WGS 84.  However, QGis says it is EPSG:4019 so maybe that is the problem.

How can I import it with this SRID?  When I try to change the SRID it fails.

```
SELECT UpdateGeometrySRID('public', 'precinct', 'geom', 4326);
ERROR:  Geometry has Z dimension but column does not
```

Comment: The error message may be trying to say that you're using a 2D (latitude-longitude) CRS but the data is 3D. Try using 4979 instead. This states that the Z values are ellipsoidal heights which is probably not true though.

Comment: for what's it's worth ... I downloaded a sample of your file. it appears to have .prj file with a projection. and it seems to be ESRI:102749 . But it's not the same for each shapefile, so check the .prj file and google it.

Comment: Looking at the projections is a great tip. They are using different projections on the state level.

Comment: Convert prj to ESPG.  In most cases is this the same as the SRID?
http://prj2epsg.org/search

Answer (score 0):

Either you cannot set a SRID for a geometry column that has multiple projections or you cannot do this if the projections are incompatible.